# Filling in a response string from within a transaction

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When submitting a transaction via 'composer-rest-server' I encapsulate the input parameters in form of JSON-body inside requests. However, I always receive the same JSON-String inside the Body-Response. Is there a way to return some response string from transaction written with JS that will be propagated to the caller inside Response-Body? How is the reverse communication to the caller foreseen in the composer? -- Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with Hyperledger v0.6 -- there's no way to synchronously propagate return value to the submitter of a transaction.

Comment: Is there any asynchronous way to do that? Of course, one could insert the answer into a "response" asset and read it later with the REST API GET method. Is there a nicer way for an asynchronous answer in your opinion? Is it planned to introduce this functionality in later version of the fabric?

Comment: HL v1 has better support for sending events back to the caller. We are working on porting Composer to HL v1 at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for a brief answer.